# Cannot set property $backendConnector of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: vue.js, plugins, service, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use a service globally in my Nuxt app. I've created my service, put it in a plugins and called it in my nuxt config, but I get this error. I'm not sure how to make it works.

services/backendConnector.js

```js
const backendConnector = {
  getReviews() {
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}/reviews`);
  },
  more functions like this one ...
}

export default backendConnector;
```

/plugins/backendConnector.plugin.js

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import Vue from 'vue';
import backendConnector from '@/services/backendConnector';

Vue.prototype.$backendConnector = backendConnector;
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
plugins: [
    '@/plugins/backendConnector.plugin.js',
]
```

Comment: What is `.plugin.js`? Why do you append `.plugin` to it? You meant `server`? Also, how do you expect to run your `getReviews` method? You're probably be good by [using inject](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context) here.

Comment: plugin.js is just an extension to let other dev know this is a plugin, shouldn't change a thing. I expect to use this.$backendConnector.getReviews